# Drupal mobile theme doesn't display image

Tags: 6, theming

I am working on a mobile version of a drupal  website and I am using [mobile tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) to switch theme between desktop version and mobile version based on url. I am using [fusion mobile](http://drupal.org/project/fusion_mobile) theme on the mobile side.
Now the matter is that no images are displayed in views in the mobile version. There is some kind of filtering that disables images on the theme but I can't find out where is that.

Comment: I have also tried [Nokia Mobile](http://drupal.org/project/nokia_mobile) but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution: It was just a permission that wasn't given to the anonymous user.